# Remove a question if answer exists under a different question?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

If I ask a unique question, but a commenter points out that a solution to a DIFFERENT question on the site will also fix my problem, should I delete my question?

Comment: As in should we delete duplicates? I'd say no. Your post will serve as a "sign post" for whoever uses search keywords that bring up your post instead of the duped one

Comment: Remember Stack Overflow is not mean to help YOU per se, it's meant to be a repository of knowledge. If your question makes it so that another good answer is found easily, then good

Comment: Thats what I thought, thanks for the advice